# Issue in persisting entity with @EmbeddedId and @ElementCollection in Postgres using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to perform CRUD operation over Postgres 9 using Hibernate.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE_HISTORY_RECORD")

public class MessageHistoryRecord {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MessageCompoundKey compoundKey;

    @Column
    private String responseChannel;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Trace> traces;

    @Column
    private byte[] payload;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Composite Id entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class MessageCompoundKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9084329307727034214L;

    @Column
    private String correlatedMsgId;

    @Column
    private String messageId;

    @Column
    private String endpointId;

    //getters and setters
}
```

ElementCollection Entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class Trace implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9084329307727034214L;

    private Long timestamp;

    private String description;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I am using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to create schema for me.

It created tables for me:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."message_history_record"
(
   correlatedmsgid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   endpointid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   messageid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   payload bytea,
   responsechannel varchar(255),
   CONSTRAINT message_history_record_pkey PRIMARY KEY (correlatedmsgid,endpointid,messageid)
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX message_history_record_pkey ON "public"."message_history_record"
(
  correlatedmsgid,
  endpointid,
  messageid
)
;

CREATE TABLE "public"."messagehistoryrecord_traces"
(
   messagehistoryrecord_correlatedmsgid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   messagehistoryrecord_endpointid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   messagehistoryrecord_messageid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   description varchar(255),
   timestamp bigint
)
```

**On persisting any object, I did not find any entry in `messagehistoryrecord_traces` table.**

Hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.xx.xx.xx:5432/testdb
hibernate.connection.username=***
hibernate.connection.password=****
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.pool_size=10
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Persist sql :

> Hibernate: insert into MESSAGE_HISTORY_RECORD (payload, responseChannel, correlatedMsgId, endpointId, messageId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **StatelessSession instead of session**. As per the documentation:

> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do operations cascade to associated instances. **Collections are ignored by a stateless session**. Operations performed via a stateless session bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a first-level cache.

More details can be found on this [thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1007626&view=previous).

After using Session instead of StatelessSession, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration the defaults should apply for the table name, column names and join column names of the collection table. These defaults are constructed as follows:

1. Table name: name of the referencing entity, appended with an underscore and the name of the entity attribute that contains the element colletion ( `MessageHistoryRecord_traces`)
2. Join column: name of the referencing entity, appended
   with an underscore and the name of the primary key column of the entity table.

This second case is only allowed if you have a single primary key field in the parent entity which is not the case in your case. So you have specify the join column yourself as follows (I renamed the collection table name and foreign key column names because they are too long for my database system):

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "mhr_traces", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="mhr_correlatedmsgid", referencedColumnName="correlatedmsgid"), 
                 @JoinColumn(name="mhr_endpointid", referencedColumnName="endpointid"), 
                 @JoinColumn(name = "mhr_messageid", referencedColumnName = "messageid")})
private List<Trace> traces = new ArrayList<>();
```

And one more thing: you have to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for the primary key class if you haven't done yet (they are not visible in your post).

Your table creation script is also missing the foreign key definitino (add them manually if they are not generated automatically):

```
CONSTRAINT mrFK FOREIGN KEY (mhr_correlatedmsgid, mhr_endpointid, mhr_messageid) REFERENCES MESSAGE_HISTORY_RECORD (correlatedmsgid,endpointid,messageid)
```

Adjust it matching to your database syntax (I don't know PostgreSQL)

With these adjustments everything works for me; indeed on an Oracle database system and EclipseLink as persistence provider. I think it is not implementation specific

Comment: I implemented `equals()` and `hashcode()`. Issue is with the usage of StatelessSession.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add anything to your traces list or it was empty??
It is working for me with postgresql without any tweaks. With hbm2ddl.auto set to update, hibernate created the tables and foreign key relationship between them as well. Here is the sample code I used :

```
public class App 
{
     public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + Postgresql");
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            MessageCompoundKey cKey = new MessageCompoundKey();
            cKey.setCorrelatedMsgId("correlatedMsgId_2");
            cKey.setEndpointId("endpointId_2");
            cKey.setMessageId("messageId_2");

            MessageHistoryRecord record = new MessageHistoryRecord();
            record.setResponseChannel("ArsenalFanTv");

            List<Trace> traces = new ArrayList<>();
            Trace t1 = new Trace();
            t1.setDescription("description_1");
            t1.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            traces.add(t1);
            Trace t2 = new Trace();
            t2.setDescription("description_2");
            t2.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            traces.add(t2);

            record.setCompoundKey(cKey);
            record.setTraces(traces);

            session.save(record);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
}
```

and my configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml) is as follows :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <!--  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.skm.schema.MessageHistoryRecord"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Yes your example worked for me. Issue is with the usage of StatelessSession.